# Graphing Multiple Variables Using Python and Seaborn/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to create a graph that combines these three variables. I want to do this so I can see if the team's average win rating has an effect on the home crowd attendance. I have attached an image of what my data frame looks like. I am open to multiple graphs and would love to look at multiple different solutions for this if possible! [image: Link to the data frame is here]

Here is an example code to get you started. `nba = pd.DataFrame([['Spurs', 18459.4, .741800], ['Thunder', 18203.0, 676800], ['Clippers', 19203.4, .662600], ['Warriors', 19403.6, .650000]], columns = ['Team', 'Home: Avg Attendance', 'Winning Percentage'])`

Comment: Can you please include your dataframe as a copyable piece of code, rather than an image file (makes testing easier)?

Comment: @HenryEcker I am fairly new to Python so I am unsure what you are looking for when you say a copyable piece of code. This is a merged data frame between two Excel sheets. I was able to use the to_csv function and saved it to my computer. I am unable to upload a CSV in the question for some reason but I can send it to you some other way.

Comment: See. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888)

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you! Editing original post with that code now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph function of pandas python package, allows you to create a composite graph with the number of spectators and the winning percentage. This is the simplest example.

```
nba.set_index('Team', inplace=True)

nba['Home: Avg Attendance'].plot(kind='bar')
nba['Winning Percentage'].plot(secondary_y=True, style='g', rot=90, figsize=(12,6)
```

[image]

Comment: When I did this the graph was super squished together and I couldn't read any of the team names and the bar plots are too close together and not readable. Do you know how to stretch it out and make it readable?

Comment: `figsize=(12,9)`For example, you can use this to set the size of the width and height.

Comment: I got it from your edit. Thank you for the help I appreciate it!  :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer